# MySQL delete after timeout

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file that is ran every so often to delete old rows of data. Inside the PHP file I have example.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table1 where timeout < $timestamp");
```

The problem I notice lately since I have about 11 of those lines for 11 different tables ran all at once every so often.

I now notice more lines I add it won't delete the rows on certain tables. If I run it manually like this

```
DELETE FROM table1 where timeout < 1337143007
```

It will delete the old rows fine. So am I missing something am I running Delete From on to many tables at once?

Thank you

Comment: The issue is definitely not in the amount of tables. It is 100% that your query/queries is/are incorrect. To know for sure - show us **plain** queries, without php variables

Comment: `$timestamp` isn't properly escaped in your first query perhaps?  What is the value of `$timestamp`?

Comment: i do this to a few million rows in a few thousand tables on the first of every month. $q="DELETE from DB WHERE date_start < NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY";

Comment: 1337143007 is what $timestamp looks like...

Comment: Probably need more code to help you with this one.

Comment: That's pretty much it except for the MySQL connect.

Comment: why work with a UNIX TIMESTAMP rather than a more user friendly timestamp. what's easier to read:  2005-03-27 03:00:00 or 1111885200 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table1 where timeout < $timestamp");
```

The only possible culprit here seams to be your `$timestamp`.
Try to echoing/log the query as you run-it and you'll probably find the culprit.

Comment: It wasn't displaying the timestamp but the php time code is fine gotta figure out why it won't show it sometimes.